# how to add audio in c code block

Tags: c++, audio

I am making a Game show application and I wanted to add audio files inside my program.

```
Question
User Input (answer)
If Statement 
    --correct
        --Play cheering audio clip
    --incorrect
        --Play disappoint audio clip
```

I have a windows 7 computer, and Im using Code Block.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx) should work.

Comment: If you want something a little more advanced (and cross platform), the [`bass`](http://www.un4seen.com/) library is pretty good.

Comment: Erm... Is this C or C++?

Comment: If you're releasing it for free you could use FMOD Ex programmers API. If you are charging some money then you may want something with a free licesne like OpenAL. FMOD would be easier. There are lots of implementations of OpenAL that could make it easier, its a little like OpenGL, fairly simple to use but you need to use a fair amount of library functions in the correct order.